# Saving a record with Has_Many_Through records in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm getting "spans invalid" error when saving a job record that:

```
#job.rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :workspans
    has_many :spans, through: :workspans
end
```

I didn't get this error in rails 5.0, but on upgrading, I can't associate the spans.

The data is coming from a fairly standard rails form, with a checkbox for each span.

```
#new.html.erb
<%= Span.each do |span| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "job[span_ids][]", span.id %>
<% end %>
```

What has changed and how should I now set up the form to associate the spans with the @job ?

UPDATE, Detail

```
#jobs_controller
  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)    
    if @job.save
      flash[:success] = "Job Saved"
      redirect_to  action: :index
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Job Not Saved"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you add some more information like controllers, models etc to the description?
Also, please mention what is the exact error you are looking at?

Comment: That is the exact error

Comment: @KartikeyTanna - more details added.

Comment: Is it related to you? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23960
From Rails 5.2 `required: true` is the default. You need to mention `optional: true`

Comment: I wondered that @KartikeyTanna but I'm ok with the belongs_to's on the workspan model being required.  Is it because there is no job_id because job hasn't been created maybe?

Comment: ah, no.  it's because in the Span model, there are some belongs_to associations that were not set and did not have , optional: true set.  this meant the span was invalid, and Rails was noticing that, even though I wasn't really trying to save the span, just the relationship to it

Comment: @KartikeyTanna - thanks for the steer. : )

Comment: you're welcome. Posted an answer out of comment so that other users can find it easily.

Comment: it's a horribly vague error message

Comment: Yeah. But release notes would help while upgrading the versions. Need to go through each related point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Rails 5.2 `belongs_to` is required by default. You need to mention `optional: true` to remove the error.

The related PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937

The related issue on Rails repo: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23960